# JQuery request not working in Chrome and Firefox. Works in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a WCF service being hosted locally and a website also being hosted locally. I make a GET ajax request for JSON data which I handle on success. I have a problem where in Chrome and Firefox it goes into the error block of the Ajax request.

```
 <!--jQuery dependencies-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Library/JS/pqgrid.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jqNew = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

Because of the complexity of the website, I am using two different versions of JQuery. The newer version has the alias of jqNew.

```
jqNew(document).ready(function () {
        $($.ajax({
            url: "http://wks52025:82/WcfDataService.svc/GetNotesFromView()?$format=json",
            type: "GET",
            datatype: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (data, textStatus) {
                alert(textStatus);
                $.each(data.d, function (i, item) {
                    alert(i);
                    DataArray[i] = [];
                    DataArray[i][0] = item.NotesID;
                    DataArray[i][1] = item.NotesTitle;
                    DataArray[i][2] = item.NotesText;
                    DataArray[i][3] = item.ProfileName;
                    DataArray[i][4] = item.IsShared;
                    DataArray[i][5] = item.NameOfUser;
                });
            },
            error: function (data, textStatus) {
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        })).then(buildGrid(DataArray));
```

This is my request. It is synchronous because I want the data before I build my grid. It is a GET request because all I want is to retrieve data. I am not doing a cross-domain request because everything is happening locally, at least I think it's local because the website and service is localhost.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <copyright file="WebDataService.cs" company="Microsoft">
//     Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
// </copyright>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
using System;
using System.Data.Services;
using System.Data.Services.Common;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Services.Parsing;
using WCFNotes;

[JSONPSupportBehavior]
public class WcfDataService : DataService< GenesisOnlineEntities >
{
    // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        // TODO: set rules to indicate which entity sets and service operations are visible, updatable, etc.
        // Examples:
         config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
         config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
         config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
         HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
         config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("GetNotes", ServiceOperationRights.AllRead);
         config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("GetNotesFromView", ServiceOperationRights.AllRead);
         config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("AddNewNote", ServiceOperationRights.All);
         config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("UpdateNote", ServiceOperationRights.All);
         config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("DeleteNote", ServiceOperationRights.All);
    }

    protected override void OnStartProcessingRequest(ProcessRequestArgs args)
        {
            base.OnStartProcessingRequest(args);
            //Cache for a minute based on querystring            
            //HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
            HttpCachePolicy c = HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache;
            c.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            //c.SetExpires(HttpContext.Current.Timestamp.AddSeconds(60));
            c.VaryByHeaders["Accept"] = true;
            c.VaryByHeaders["Accept-Charset"] = true;
            c.VaryByHeaders["Accept-Encoding"] = true;
            c.VaryByParams["*"] = true;
        }

    [WebGet]
        public IQueryable<tblNote> GetNotes()
        {
            IQueryable<tblNote> biglist = (from c in this.CurrentDataSource.tblNotes select c);
            return biglist;
        }

    [WebGet]
    public IQueryable<vw_Note> GetNoteByID(Guid NoteID)
    {
        IQueryable<vw_Note> biglist = (from c in this.CurrentDataSource.vw_Notes where c.NotesID.Equals(NoteID) select c);
        return biglist;
    }



    [WebGet]
    public IQueryable<vw_Note> GetNotesFromView()
    {
        Guid UserID = new Guid("8b0e303a-68aa-49a5-af95-d994e2bdd5ac");
        IQueryable<vw_Note> biglist = (from c in this.CurrentDataSource.vw_Notes select c);
        return biglist;
    }

    //[WebGet]
    //public void AddNewNote(string ParamNoteTitle, string ParamNoteText)
    //{

    //    //My hardcoded values for now...
    //    int ParentID = 8879;
    //    int JobID = 1000088150;
    //    int ContactID = 309;
    //    Guid UserID = Guid.NewGuid();
    //    string RelatedType = "Advertiser Contact";
    //    bool IsShared = true;

    //    tblNote N = new tblNote
    //    {
    //      NotesTitle = ParamNoteTitle,
    //      NotesText = ParamNoteText,
    //      ParentID = ParentID,
    //      ContactID = ContactID,
    //      JobID = JobID,
    //      UserID = UserID,
    //      GroupID = null,
    //      RelatedType = RelatedType,
    //      IsShared = IsShared
    //    };
    //    try
    //    {
    //        this.CurrentDataSource.tblNotes.Add(N);
    //        this.CurrentDataSource.SaveChanges();

    //    }
    //    catch (Exception ex)
    //    {

    //    }

    //}

    [WebGet]
    public IQueryable<vw_Note> AddNewNote(string ParamNoteTitle, string ParamNoteText)
    {
        //My hardcoded values for now...
        int ParentID = 8879;
        int JobID = 1000088150;
        int ContactID = 309;
        Guid UserID = new Guid("8b0e303a-68aa-49a5-af95-d994e2bdd5ac");
        Guid NoteID = Guid.NewGuid();
        string RelatedType = "Advertiser Contact";
        bool IsShared = true;

        tblNote N = new tblNote
        {
            NotesID = NoteID,
            NotesTitle = ParamNoteTitle,
            NotesText = ParamNoteText,
            ParentID = ParentID,
            ContactID = ContactID,
            JobID = JobID,
            UserID = UserID,
            GroupID = null,
            RelatedType = RelatedType,
            IsShared = IsShared
        };
        try
        {
            this.CurrentDataSource.tblNotes.Add(N);
            this.CurrentDataSource.SaveChanges();
            return GetNoteByID(NoteID);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return GetNoteByID(NoteID);
        }
    }

    [WebGet]
    public IQueryable<vw_Note> UpdateNote(string NoteID, string ParamNoteTitle, string ParamNoteText)
    {
        //My hardcoded values for now...
        Guid GNoteID = Guid.Parse(NoteID);

        try
        {
            tblNote n = CurrentDataSource.tblNotes.First(i => i.NotesID == GNoteID);
            n.NotesTitle = ParamNoteTitle;
            n.NotesText = ParamNoteText;
            this.CurrentDataSource.SaveChanges();
            return GetNoteByID(GNoteID);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return GetNoteByID(GNoteID);
        }
    }

    [WebGet]
    public IQueryable<vw_Note> DeleteNote(string NoteID)
    {
        Guid GNoteID = Guid.Parse(NoteID);
        tblNote N = new tblNote
        {
            NotesID = GNoteID,
        };
        try
        {
            this.CurrentDataSource.tblNotes.Attach(N);
            this.CurrentDataSource.tblNotes.Remove(N);
            this.CurrentDataSource.SaveChanges();

            // IF doesn't return value, delete was successful
            return GetNoteByID(GNoteID);    

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return GetNoteByID(GNoteID);    
        }
    }
}
```

This is my WCF service. Configuration is at the top of the code block.

Anyone know why this doesn't work in firefox and chrome?

Comment: If the port is different, then it's a cross origin request.

Comment: @dystroy Ok then it is cross-domain. The website is being debugged via Visual Studio and the service is hosted in iis with port 82.

Comment: Did you had the relevant CORS headers so that the page can read the data ?

Comment: @dystroy I think so. I will put my service code also. That will answer your question.

Comment: I don't know IIS but it looks good.

Comment: What are the values of the 3 parameters given to the error callback (the third must be the error) ?

Comment: @dystroy my textStatus param just says error in the alert message

Comment: the error callback is provided three arguments. The most interesting is the third one.

Comment: @dystroy Your right it is. This is the error: "Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101"

Comment: @dystroy That message is in chrome. For firefox it is [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIXMLHttpRequest.send]"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: http://localhost:8192/alf/Library/JS/jquery.min.js :: anonymous :: line 141"  data: no]